# sassc-rails is having hard time parsing css rgb function

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, sass, sass-rails

I have the following css class in `application.css`

```
.shadow {
  box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0 rgb(3 32 20/.50)!important;
}
```

When try to precompile assets the sass parser throws this error:

```
rake aborted!
remote:        SassC::SyntaxError: Error: Function rgb is missing argument $green.
remote:                on line 76 of stdin
remote:        >>   box-shadow: 0 10px 30px 0 rgb(3 32 20/.50)!important;
```

If I put commas `rgb(3, 32, 20/.50)` the parser sees no error but the problem is that the version with commas is not a valid css.

Does anyone have any idea where the error might be?